# nginx multiple domain issue

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04, laravel-5.4

I want to host two website on my ubuntu VPS  with nginx . so i created two copy of default config :`domain1.com` and `domain2.com`

config for domain1.com:

```
server {
        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;

   root /home/sher/ftp/www/public;
  server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #

       location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
             }
}
```

if user type in `www.domain1.com` in browser he would see `domain1` site. but if he hit it without `www` he would see `domain2.com` .i've created symlinks from these two config files to `sites-enabled` .

P.S : I set `listen` to `default_server` for domain1 and it seems the issue solved but im not sure if it is the right way.

Comment: removed `default` config file from `sites-enabled` ?

Comment: yes, i have two config files `domain1.com` and `domain2.com` in sites-enabled directory

Comment: you tried to `reload nginx` after changing the config?

Comment: tried but getting :`reload: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused`. btw i've reboot server before. nothing changed

Comment: Look at the error log and look at the two `server_name` directives for a typo.

Comment: What is the configuration for `domain2.com`?

Comment: the same as `domain1` but `root` and `sever_name` are changed